# Trouble removing entire line in VBS with regex

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm trying to remove an entire line (including the break line) from a text file using regex.

This is my code:

```
Do Until objFileToRead1.AtEndOfStream
    nline = objFileToRead1.ReadLine()
    regEx.Pattern = ".*to "
    nline = regEx.Replace(nline, "")
    objFileToRead2.WriteLine nline
Loop
```

That's fine and work as expected.
So, if my text file contains:

```
hahahaha to 
hehehehe to hihihihi
hohohoho to
```

It becomes:

```
(blank line)
hehehehe to hihihihi
(blank line)`
```

However, I don't want the blank like. I already tried using `regEx.Pattern = ".*to \r\n"` but it seems that the `\r\n` from the regex is not working, everytime I try to run the script like that it does not remove anything (as the search is not finding anything). Also tried to encapsulate the expression with parenthesis and brackets but no luck.

Any tips with that?

Comment: Does it mean your `nline` is empty when there is a match? Just  check it before writing to file - `If Len(nline) > 0 Then objFileToRead2.WriteLine nline`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually I'm trying to replace every line that ends with `to ` with nothing but this 'nothing' means that the line should be deleted instead of staying blank.

Comment: Read the solution below. The issue is that you still write the empty line with `.WriteLine`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReadLine reads the next line in the stream. The result does not contain the line-break, so there is no `\r\n` for your regex to match.

To prevent empty lines in the output, just don't call `WriteLine` when `nline` is empty. Or, in your case, only write the line to the output when it doesn't match your regex pattern.

Here is what I would do:

```
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "to \S+"

Do Until objFileToRead1.AtEndOfStream
    line = objFileToRead1.ReadLine
    If Not regEx.Test(line) Then objFileToRead2.WriteLine line
Loop
```

Further notes:

- There is no need keep re-defining the regex pattern in the loop.
- Since you seem to be looking for a fixed string, regex might not be necessary. You could use the [`InStr()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c(v=vs.84).aspx) to do that. For large input files there will be a performance benefit.

Comment: Your pattern would match (and therefore skip) "hehehehe to hihihihi".

Comment: You're right. Fixed according to the OP's original regex.

Comment: Hey, I was already coding based on the @Ekkehard.Horner answer. In the end the code became almost the same as your answer. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Yeah, I was writing it without seeing that he had already written a very similar answer. No worries. :)

Comment: @Adami - you should accept the **best** not the first answer.

Answer (score 3):

After

```
nline = objFileToRead1.ReadLine()
```

`nline` does not contain a trailing vbCrLf resp. \r\n, so your new RegExp can't match.

If you want only lines with something interesting after the "to", just .WriteLine to the output file **only if** `nline` matches "to \S+$" (to, one blank, one or more non-whilespaces before then end). I.E.: Forget about the Replace.

Comment: Thanks, that enlightened me. I have to adjust the regexp to "to \S+" because there was more text after that before the end of the line.